# Error para alinear formulario a la izquierda

Tags: php, html, laravel, formato, bootstrap

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="numero">NUMERO</label>
 <input type="int" name="numero"  class="form-control" placeholder="numero...">
</div>
</div>
```

pero en la vista los muestra asi

```
                                                 Numero            Ciudad
                                                 Municipio         Gobernador
```

Cómo hago para que me queden alineados al margen izquierdo es decir no se centre a la derecha?

Comment: Que framework usas?

Comment: Estoy usando laravel

Comment: Hablo del frontend amigo

Comment: Utilizo boostrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la forma correcta en estos casos es que tengas tu propio archivo de estilos con css ,veo que estas introduciendo bootstrap en tu pagina por lo que te recmiento que intentes lo siguiente:
tu div que queden asi:

```
<div class="midiv">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="numero">NUMERO</label>
        <input type="int" name="numero"  class="form-control" placeholder="numero...">
    </div>
</div>
```

si observas al div principal le agrege una clase (midiv) esto para controlar su tamaño en el css el cual es un archivo aparte al que llame estilos.css y dentro coloque esto:

```
.midiv{
    width:200px;
}
```

y luego en tu etiqueta  metes un link asi:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
```

esta es la forma mas correcta ojo en el atributo href vas a poner la direccion del archivo si tu tienes tu archivo css en la misma carpeta que tu pagina pues solo pones el nombre del archivo con tu extencion y si lo tienes en el mismo lugar pero en una carpeta aparte pues pones por ejemplo: css/estilos.css aqui estoy indicando que mi archivo estilos css se encuentra en la misma carpeta que mi pagina pero dentro de otra carpeta llamada css por darte un ejemplo

Comment: una discula ya elimine la primera respuesta para que no exista confucion